# I need a way to have link text without any styling/formatting

Tags: html, css, sharepoint, cross-browser

I have to put a content editor web part onto a SharePoint page. The page have a css file linked. I can't remove the link and can't modify the css.

What I want is a 1 row table with `n` columns, and a link in each column. To avoid the default link style I tried to include the `td` within the `a` tag:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <a href="link"><td>text</td></a>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This works perfectly in IE but not in other browsers (Chrome, Firefox). According to an online validator (http://www.freeformatter.com/html-validator.html) this is not very good:

`<a> Isn't Allowed In <tr> Elements (At line 3, column 13)`

If I simply do it vice versa the link will be formatted:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="link">text</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Even if I do put the below in the beginning of the code, it won't be applied:

```
<style>
    a {
        color: #000000;
    }
</style>
```

I could do a transparent background image for the `td` with the text "burned" in it, and put the `img` tag into the `a`, but it will be ugly if I zoom on it.

So is there a way which will work in any browser to bypass the css somehow?

*EDIT: Also tried:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="link"><div>text</div></a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The other css file is included in the `head`, so mine should be under it.

Comment: Yes, I did try that.

Comment: No, it didn't. Believe me, I would tell you if it was.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64394/discussion-between-deer-outdoor-nl-and-fishmong3r).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get my css settings applied:

```
<style>
    a {
        color: #000000 !important;        
    }
</style>
```

With the above code I just wanted to show which way I choose. Actually I used:

```
.myTable a{color: #000000 !important;}
```

Comment: With this you have stylized ALL <a> element on the page, better to use instead a class.

Comment: @Max Certainly, I used the id of my table. I was just lazy to copy paste the code. Sorry for that.